# How to free up memory on viewwilldisappear MKMapView?

Tags: ios, memory-management, mkmapview

Hello everyone I have a MKMapView in my uiviewcontroller. When i open the uiview the memory heap rises from 20 Mb to 100 Mb. And on viewwilldisappear i have added the following:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
     [self.mapView release];
}
```

But the memory stays the same. Its does not decrease.

Comment: Are you also releasing any data displayed in the `MKMapView` like annotations. Also I'm missing a call to `[super viewWillDisappear:animated];` in your methods. If you are able to update I would suggest you use ARC since it will be less of a hassle then dealing with memory management your self.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

MKMapviews are always found to be leaky. you need to apply something like this

Set the map view's delegate to nil, which will prevent MKMapView from sending messages to it.

> ```
> self.mapView.showsUserLocation = NO;
> self.mapView.delegate = nil;
> [self.mapView removeFromSuperview];
> self.mapView = nil;
> ```

Also you can change map type when you get memory warning

This is what apple says

> Before releasing an MKMapView object for which you have set a
>   delegate, remember to set that object’s delegate property to nil. One
>   place you can do this is in the dealloc method where you dispose of
>   the map view.

Comment: Great :) Enjoy coding :)